# Running java script with bat, "java is not recognized as an internal command or external command"

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

Ok Guys Thank you for trying to debug me.

I have a java script that i usually compile with this cmd

```
javac -classpath jxl.jar;..C:\3DWIP\src\; GenerateExcel.java
```

then I run it with this cmd.

```
java -classpath jxl.jar;..C:\3DWIP\src\; GenerateExcel Model.STEPFILE
```

jxl.jar being the JExcelAPI for writing an EXCEL file and C:\3DWIP\src\ is the folder where my Main() would be.

This works perfectly.

My problem is that I have a bat script that at some point is supposed to call the javac and the java and for example when it calls the following line
    java -classpath jxl.jar;..C:\3DWIP\src\; GenerateExcel Model.STEPFILE

I get the famous "java is not recognized as an internal command or external command".

This is my system path variables

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\3DWIP\src;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\lib\jexcelapi\jxl.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

This is my bat script

```
@echo off

set INPUTFILENAME=%~1
set INPUTFILENAME=%INPUTFILENAME:C:\GENERATOR\=%
set CTWORKFLD=C:\GENERATOR\
set CTINSTDIR=C:\coretechnologie2014\evolution64
set CTSCRIPTFLD=C:\coretechnologie2014\evolution64\scripts
set CTLIBPATH=C:\coretechnologie2014\evolution64\lib64
set EVOLPATH=%CTINSTDIR%
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.00_67\bin;%EVOLPATH%;%CTLIBPATH%;%CTLIBPATH%\lib3dx\intel_a\code\bin;%UGII_ROOT_DIR%;

rmdir %CTWORKFLD%\out /s /q

mkdir %CTWORKFLD%\out

echo Processing file: %INPUTFILENAME%

echo Exporting Images and Data 
"%CTINSTDIR%\evolution.exe" -batch "%CTSCRIPTFLD%\Compute_Properties_and_views.scp"     "%CTWORKFLD%\%INPUTFILENAME%" Evolution Step "%CTWORKFLD%\out\%INPUTFILENAME%" "%CTWORKFLD%\out\%INPUTFILENAME%.stp.log"

echo Exporting Done!

echo Generating Excel File

chdir /d C:\3DWIP\src
::javac -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;..jxl.jar;..C:\3DWIP\src\; GenerateExcel.java 
java -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;..jxl.jar;..C:\3DWIP\src\; GenerateExcel %INPUTFILENAME%


echo Closing 1000 secs... 
"%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" /t 1000 /nobreak
echo Job Done!


@echo  
@echo
```

Pls help I duno what to do anymore.

Comment: Did you set %JAVA_HOME% ? If yes, have you checked it ?

Comment: The message says that Windows can't find `java.exe`.  Your `.bat` script changes the `PATH`.  Apparently `java.exe` does not exist in any of the directories on that path, but did exist in one of the directories in the `PATH` you were using before.  If `java.exe` actually does exist in one of the directories in the new `PATH`, please clarify.

Comment: Try using `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk_*\bin\java.exe args`, directly referencing the java.exe path or including a jre.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty noob, I dont know if I have set %JAVA_HOME%, how do i do that, i have %JAVA_HOME%àbin in my environement PATH..otherwise i dont know how/where to set.

Comment: What Path am I using now If my PATH has been overwritten..Where can i manage that?

Comment: Your script obliterated everything in your environment path when you said `set path=`.  Probably change this to `set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.00_67\bin;.........` which *adds* directories to the path but keeps the old ones.  Or you can put `;%PATH%` at the end.  I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, your problem is probably just a typo.  Are you sure it's supposed to be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.00_67\bin`, with two `0`'s?  The rest of your script has just one `0`.

Comment: thanks alot ajb what your saying makes alot of sense, especially when you pointed out the fact that set path obliterates my existing path. 
I will try your solution...

The bat script is actually a script generated by the program 3devolution in order to output 4 images and a txt file. The program added the set path, and thus fking me all up. :) Ill get back to you..

Comment: That was it a mix of two bugs, the typo for the java version, and the missig %PATH% after set path=..... Thank you guys

Comment: How Do I mark as answered^

Comment: @Lethal420 You should see a big check mark by the answer--click on that and turn it green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably just a typo in your `SET PATH` command: it refers to
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.00_67` while the rest of your script is referring to
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67`.  But I'd like to explain in general how to add things to a `PATH`.

In Windows, `SET PATH=` will set up a list of directories that is searched for `.exe` files.  (In your case, it's looking for `java.exe`.)  However, doing this does not automatically retain directories in the previous `PATH`.  It's a really simple command--it just sets the variable to the string you give it.

To *add* directories to the `PATH` while keeping the previous directories, use a command like

```
SET PATH=<dir1>;<dir2>;<dir3>;%PATH%
```

or

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;<dir1>;<dir2>;<dir3>
```

Which one you use will make a difference if there's an `.exe` file in more than one path directory, since Windows will look through the directories in order to find the `.exe` file it's looking for.  In many cases the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows 7 or 8, these would be the steps to set the Java classpath for permanent.

(i) Open up your "System Properties" dialog. Click the "Advanced system settings" option from the left side pane. 

(ii) In the following window, navigate to "Advanced" tab. You will now see the "Environment Variables..." button and click it. 

(iii) In the another following window, if you find a "Path" variable, just double click it. 

(iv) In the "Edit System Variable" window, type your Java bin directory path. For most instance, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;" or you can also type "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;". The path could change in the Java directory since the version varies. So, make sure it. Note the semicolon at the end of the path as it is must and if the Java classpath comes after another path in the Path variable then place the semicolon at the front of it either. 

(v) Now, just close all the opened windows by clicking "OK".

These steps are more effective than making on "Command Line" since the command line persists these settings only as long as the "Command Prompt" is opened.